# Windows service not executing after first run

Tags: windows-services

I have create a windows service in VS 2010. I install it and also run it at the same time and set `startup` type to `Automatic` . I see it running fine through `EventViewer` and is successfully completed.

But after that i done see `EventViewer` showing anything, even if the work is doen it still should check DB and skip as all rows done.

So what is the issue ?

DO i need to make it an infinite loop in the service to keep it running?

Something like

While (ROWs in DB ! = null) ?

Because it does not seem it is working like task scheduler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to do a loop with the possibility to break it again. Example service (VB.NET):

```
Public Class MyService

    Protected Property IsRunning As Boolean = False

    Protected Sub OnStart(args() As String)
        IsRunning = True
        ' make the loop function run asynchronously
        Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf MyLoopFunction)
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub MyLoopFunction
        While IsRunning

            ' here comes your code ...

            ' sleep for a second for better CPU freedom
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End While
    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnStop()
        IsRunning = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is my first time making a windows service will this not overload the system in any way?

Comment: As long as you have some sleep mechanism in the service it won't. Depending on your needs you can choose a large interval. Other services work the same way and hopefully they take care of performance, too.

Comment: A ISSUE IN THIS APPROACH THE SERVICE STATUS REMAING ON STARTING... AS I LOOP IT IN START FUNCTION !

Comment: That's why I put the loop in a separate method.