# Named pipes in service causes high CPU usage

Tags: c#

I wrote a service that runs a thread that sets some settings once a minute.

The service does what it is supposed to do, but then it was noticed that it makes the CPU usage go very high (about 25% on a dual core).

Using trial and error I found that the following objects are causing the problem:

```
private AsyncPipes.NamedPipeStreamServer pipeServer = new NamedPipeStreamServer("NotifyToService");
private AsyncPipes.NamedPipeStreamClient pipeClient = new NamedPipeStreamClient("ServiceToNotify");
```

Is it normal for named pipes to use so much CPU, just by being instantiated?

Comment: Probably need to show your code.

Comment: You might want to make use of a sleep interval. See this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150856/windows-service-not-executing-after-first-run/17151266#17151266

Comment: Have you observed what happens if you run another program that's CPU intensive as well?

Comment: There's a thread on MSDN forums about this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bbf5a0b-3c22-4836-b271-999e514c321b/namedpipeclientstreamconnect-causes-cpu-hang-is-there-a-workaround

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can replicate your results (except 13% on my 8-core CPU). I had to download and build the AsyncPipes library from the end of [this article](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1433/make-your-apps-talk-to-each-other-asynchronous-named-pipes-library.aspx). The problem is that the code in `NamedPipeStreamClient` is throwing a `System.TimeoutException` once per second.

In a manner of bad design, the constructor of `NamedPipeStreamClient` is calling a method called `StartTryConnect()` after setting some class members.

That method, in turn, starts a background thread which calls the method `TryConnect`. It goes into a tight loop here:

```
while (!this._Stream.IsConnected)
{
    try
    {
        ((NamedPipeClientStream) this._Stream).Connect(0x3e8);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Until the server your client is trying to connect to ("ServiceToNotify") is actually started, this is going to be the case. However, I don't see anywhere where you have a named pipe server named that (you have the opposite, "NotifyToService") started up.

However, once it does connect to the server, the CPU usage will drop as expected.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The solution would be to change the code so that it only tries to connect when it is reasonable to expect that there be a listener at the other end. Since this is a service with an agent application, the agent application will only start up later when the user logs in. Or to increase the timeout duration.

Comment: I added a `Thread.sleep(20000)` in the `catch` block. Problem solved.

Comment: Surprised by the silly design of NamedPipeClientStream.Connect() method

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using to avoid this problem. It is a very simplified version of a solution shown on this MSDN forum thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bbf5a0b-3c22-4836-b271-999e514c321b/namedpipeclientstreamconnect-causes-cpu-hang-is-there-a-workaround

```
  [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
  [DllImport( "kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true )]
  private static extern bool WaitNamedPipe( string name, int timeout );


  /// <summary>
  /// Method to test if Windows considers that a named pipe of a certain name exists or not.
  /// </summary>
  internal static bool DoesNamedPipeExist(string pipeFileName)
  {
     try
     {
        return WaitNamedPipe(@"\\.\pipe\" + pipeFileName, 0);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
```

This is the bit of code around the place where the NamedPipeClientStream.Connect() method is used:

```
 // If necessary, wait for the server end to open the named pipe. Otherwise the following 
 //  NamedPipeClientStream.Connect() method can burn up 100% CPU time while waiting for 
 //  the connection. 
 while (true)
 {
    if (DoesNamedPipeExist(_pipeFileName))
       break;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }

 // Connect to named pipe server - this is a blocking call, and in fact is a blocking 
 //  call that can use 100% CPU time while waiting for a connection
 _namedPipeClient.Connect();
```

Comment: It boggles the mind reading the Pipe code on referencesource. This is a great workaround. Thanks.