# c# named pipes detect server shutdown

Tags: c#

In c# namedpipes have the horrible characteristics to get into loops of full cpu load during connecting (waiting for server), and in my case, also when the server is closing leaving the client alone. And this is my question: Can the client detect a server shutdown (server disconnect) by events? 
Currently I run a timer, testing the connection every 2nd second. This works as I can close the connection in the client and dispose the namedpipeclientstram what stops the high cpu load. However it means in worst case there is very high cpu load for up to 2 seconds.

However to avoid any high cpu load at all I´m searching an kind of event system to detect one-sided connection shutdown of the server in the client. Is there any? I have not found anything so far.

It would be also ok to force the client stream not to seek reconnection when 
server is closing (at least it looks like this is happening as it resembles very much the cpu state during a wait for the server)
The connection is bidirectional and async.

One more question about named pipes: When the server is up and ready, would it be ok to try to connect as client with a specified timeout of 0? Does this specify at least one trial, immediatly returning if server is not up?
Or does the timeout has be at least as high as network delays or server response times are ?

Thx for help
Stefan

Comment: The high cpu load is the result of something in your code.  Named pipes don't do just do that by themselves.

Comment: There are multiple threads out confirming high cpu load with named pipes
e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193573/named-pipes-in-service-causes-high-cpu-usage

Comment: Yes, and as the answer says, it's a tight loop causing the issue, not the creation of the named pipe.

Comment: yes and the tight loop is inside the MS c# framework